# Winsock2.h include error

Tags: sockets

Did anyone try to include winsock2.h and then tried to compile it on cygwin? Unfortuantely
I get the following error message:

winsock2.h:635: error: declaration of C function 'int gethostname(char*, int)' conflicts with
/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:2006: error: previous declaration 'int gethostname(char, size t)' here

Does anyone know how I can fix this "bug"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`winsock2.h` is for the Windows enviroment.  The cygwin headers should contain `sys/socket.h`.  Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is an environment for compiling POSIX compliant programs on Windows. If you want to compile Windows compliant programs on Windows, use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) instead.